# Wordpress - Repeatable custom field values are outputted as a string and not an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a repeatable text field "show_on_pages", I have created a new post of this content type and added 3 values for "show_on_pages". When i run the code below

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'my_post_type');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'show_on_pages');
    print_r($meta);
endwhile;
```

It returns a string and not an array

Array ( [0] => ["page1","page2","page3"] )

If I do

```
echo $meta[0];
```

The page will print "["page1","page2","page3"]"

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meta is stored as JSON.
Do the following `$pages=json_decode($meta[0]);` and `$pages` will be an array which will look like this (from your example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => page1
    [1] => page2
    [2] => page3
)
```

Refer to this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more info on `json_decode` function.